# Woocommerce adding housenumber twice under shipping fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The house number is showing up twice in the shipping fields. I'm not sure what is causing this.

[image]

This is what my functions.php looks like at the moment in the child theme folder. Could one of these lines be causing this?

```
<?php

add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated) { 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Order number', 'Ordernummer', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Bestelnummer:', 'Ordernummer:', $translated);   
    $translated = str_ireplace('Your order', 'Uw bestelling', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Based on', 'Gebaseerd op', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Show', 'Bekijk', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Doorgaan naar afrekenen', 'Doorgaan naar volgende stap', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Add', 'Toevoegen', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Your', 'Uw', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Je winkelmand is momenteel leeg.', 'Uw winkelmand is momenteel leeg.', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('There are no reviews yet.', 'Er zijn nog geen reviews.', $translated);  
    $translated = str_ireplace('Be the first to review', 'Geef als eerste een review over', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Shipping Details', 'Verzend gegevens', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('new-price', 'Verzend gegevens', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('new price', 'Verzend gegevens', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('New price', 'Verzend gegevens', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('VAT', 'BTW', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('overall', 'Gemiddeld', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Name', 'Naam', $translated);
    $translated = str_ireplace('Assortiment Categories', 'Categoriën', $translated); 
    $translated = str_ireplace('Bedankt. Wij hebben uw bestelling ontvangen', 'Bedankt. Wij hebben uw bestelling/aanvraag ontvangen. U ontvangt z.s.m.
    een bevestiging hiervan in uw mailbox.</br> <b>Let op</b>, heeft u deze mail niet ontvangen, controleer dan uw "ongewenste post" map (spam folder).', $translated);
    return $translated; 
}

// function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
//     return 'https://www.prikkabelled.nl/overzicht-bestelling/'; 
// }
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

// Display 24 products per page. Goes in functions.php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function ( $cols ) {
    return - 1;
} );


/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Product Bundles - Default Bundled Item Quantity Override
 * Plugin URI: http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/
 * Description: Use this snippet to override the initial quantity value of a bundled item (by default equal to the minimum quantity).
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: SomewhereWarm
 * Author URI: http://www.somewherewarm.net/
 * Developer: Manos Psychogyiopoulos
 *
 * Requires at least: 3.8
 * Tested up to: 4.1
 *
 * Copyright: © 2015 Manos Psychogyiopoulos (psyx@somewherewarm.net).
 * License: GNU General Public License v3.0
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

    //global array to reposition the elements to display as you want (e.g. kept 'title' before 'first_name' )
    $wdm_address_fields = array(
        'country',
        'company',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'address_1',
        'housenumber',
        'housenr-ad',
        'city',           
        'postcode'
    );

    //global array only for extra fields
    $wdm_ext_fields = array('title', 'address_4');

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'wdm_override_default_address_fields' );

        function wdm_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ){

        $temp_fields = array();

        $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = '';
        $address_fields['address_1']['label'] = __('Street', 'woocommerce');

        $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = '';
        $address_fields['address_2']['label'] = __('Building', 'woocommerce');

        $address_fields['housenumber'] = array(
            'label' => __('Huisnr.', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'=> '',
            'required'   => true,
            'class'      => array('form-row-wide', 'address-field'),
            'type'  => 'number'
        );

        $address_fields['housenr-ad'] = array(
            'label' => __('Toevoeging', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'=> '',
            'required'   => true,
            'class'      => array('form-row-wide', 'address-field'),
            'type'  => 'text'
        );

        $address_fields['address_4'] = array(
            'label' => __('Area', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'=> '',
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide', 'address-field'),
            'type'  => 'text'
        );

        global $wdm_address_fields;

        foreach($wdm_address_fields as $fky){       
            $temp_fields[$fky] = $address_fields[$fky];
        }

        $address_fields = $temp_fields;

        return $address_fields;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'wdm_formatted_address_replacements', 99, 2);

    function wdm_formatted_address_replacements( $address, $args ){
        $address['{address_1}'] = $args['address_1'] . " " . $args['housenumber'] . $args['address_2'] . " " . $args['housenr-ad'];
        return $address;
    }

    // add_filter('woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'wdm_formatted_address_replacements2', 99, 2);

    // function wdm_formatted_address_replacements2( $address, $args ){
    //     $address['{address_2}'] = $args['address_2'] . " " . $args['postcode'] . " " . $args['Plaats']; //reposition to display as it should be
    //     return $address;
    // }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'wdm_update_formatted_billing_address', 99, 2);
        function wdm_update_formatted_billing_address( $address, $obj ){
        global $wdm_address_fields;             
        if(is_array($wdm_address_fields)){
            foreach($wdm_address_fields as $waf){
                $address[$waf] = $obj->{'billing_'.$waf};
            }
        }             
        return $address;    
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address', 'wdm_update_formatted_shipping_address', 99, 2);

    function wdm_update_formatted_shipping_address( $address, $obj ){
        global $wdm_address_fields;
        if(is_array($wdm_address_fields)){
            foreach($wdm_address_fields as $waf){
                $address[$waf] = $obj->{'shipping_'.$waf};
            }
        }   
        return $address;    
    }
?>

<?php
    add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', 'wdm_my_account_address_formatted_address', 99, 3);

    function wdm_my_account_address_formatted_address( $address, $customer_id, $name ){
        global $wdm_address_fields;
        if (is_array($wdm_address_fields)){
            foreach($wdm_address_fields as $waf){
                $address[$waf] = get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_' . $waf, true );
            }
        }
        return $address;
    }
?>

<?php
    add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'wdm_add_extra_customer_field');
    add_filter('woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'wdm_add_extra_customer_field');

    function wdm_add_extra_customer_field( $fields ){  
        $fields = wdm_override_default_address_fields( $fields );      
        global $wdm_ext_fields;
        if(is_array($wdm_ext_fields)){
            foreach($wdm_ext_fields as $wef){
                $fields[$wef]['show'] = false; //hide the way they are display by default as we have now merged them within the address field
            }
        }
        return $fields;
    }

    /* Exclude Category from Shop*/
    add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );

    function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
      $new_terms = array();

      // if a product category and on the shop page
      if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
          if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( 'overige-lampen') ) ) {
            $new_terms[] = $term;
          }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
      }
      return $terms;
    }
?>

<?php
    function theme_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'electro-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/electro-custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
?>

<?php
    // remove Order Notes from checkout field in Woocommerce
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
    function alter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
         unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
         return $fields;
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is address_1 & address_2 in your address field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code from:

```
function wdm_formatted_address_replacements( $address, $args ){
        $address['{address_1}'] = $args['address_1'] . " " . $args['housenumber'] . $args['address_2'] . " " . $args['housenr-ad'];
        return $address;
    }
```

To:

```
function wdm_formatted_address_replacements( $address, $args ){
        $address['{address_1}'] = $args['address_1'] .  $args['address_2'] . " " . $args['housenr-ad'];
        return $address;
    }
```

hope it will works!!!